# Show report viewer in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, datatable, reportviewer

everybody. I have this simple WebApp with a report viewer that should show the result of my query. I have written my code that should fetch datas via my select query. Then I wrote a little method that should display my record on a report viewer. What am I doing wrong?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showReport();
}

protected void showReport()
{ 
    rptViewer.Reset();
    DataTable dt = GetData(Convert.ToInt64(TextBox1.Text));
    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
    rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
    rptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
    ReportParameter rptParam = new ReportParameter("id_doc", TextBox1.Text);
    rptViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
}

private DataTable GetData(Int64 id_doc)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string connStr = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["logindbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {           
            string sSQL = "select * from doc_details where id_doc=";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL+ TextBox1.Text, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_doc", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            Console.WriteLine(dt);
            adp.Fill(dt);  
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.Text = ex.Message;
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Is your report viewer displaying a report or some error text when you run this?

Comment: You don't explain what issue you have but your code has issues. You are using string concatenation to create a SQL string that does *not* contain any parameters. If the textbox contains anything weird your query will fail. Your `WHERE` clause should be `where id_doc=@id_doc`.

Comment: Based on your comment to an answer below your connection string is wrong or your sql server is misconfigured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

The query must have a parameter named string @id_doc

string sSQL = "select * from doc_details where id_doc=@id_doc";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, conn);

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id_doc", TextBox1.Text));

Comment: @SimonPJ The application never reaches the showReport() method and after a long wait a connection problem is shown: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server. I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: check your connection string

Comment: Here's my connection string: <add name="logindbConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=logindb" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /> Any clue?

Comment: You can't use an sqlCommand for mySql Data base, use rather MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection)

Comment: That was one of the problems. I had to use MySqlObjects in order to make it work since I'm using a MySQL database. What a muppet. So many thanks for that. I have another problem now. Once everything was changed, I have no results on my page. I mean nothing is displayed. Any clue?

Comment: I solved it: my parameter was wrong. True parameter was: cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReportParameter1", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = TextBox1.Text;